# Why won't a System.Collections.ArrayList of int cast down to an enum type with ToArray?

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist, casting, enums

I needed this:

```
Plugin.MetaDataType[] fields =
  (Plugin.MetaDataType[]) 
  ((System.Collections.ArrayList) parameters["fields"])
      .ToArray(typeof(Plugin.MetaDataType));
```

Where Plugin.MetaDataType is a public enum of integer values in Plugin and parameters["fields"] is an ArrayList, but is seen as an object.

This yields an exception: "At least one element in the source array could not be cast down to the destination array type." Even though the source array only contains int elements and the enum of integer values.

The code above doesn't work, but the code below does, even though I think it should do the exact same thing. Why doesn't the code above work, but the code below does?

```
System.Collections.ArrayList al = (System.Collections.ArrayList)parameters["fields"];
Plugin.MetaDataType[] fields = new Plugin.MetaDataType[al.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < al.Count; i++)
{
  fields[i] = (Plugin.MetaDataType)al[i];
}
```

Comment: I don't know what API that is, but FYI, `ArrayList` has been obsolete for a decade. You should use `List<T>` if you have a choice.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using the API and it yields an ArrayList, so I have to deal with it, but I'll pass that on.

Comment: Wow! Mind saying which API? It clearly hasn't been updated in a long time.

Comment: Can you produce a short but complete program demonstrating the problem?

Comment: can you post the StackTrace ? it would help if we know which method throws the exception

Comment: BTW, `ArrayList` isn't part of C#. It's (an obsolete) part of .NET.

Comment: @JohnSaunders it's output generated by an embedded web server component by the name of HybridDSP.Net, by www.hybridgeotools.com and it *is* rather old. However, it's part of a lot of code already in place and if it ain't broke...

Comment: Thanks. Now I know to stay away from that company. It's not like .NET 2.0 came out 3 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly cast an `int` to an `enum` value, but the `ArrayList.ToArray` method won't cast `int` values to `enum` values.

The `ArrayList` has to contain values of the `enum` type for the `ArrayList.ToArray` method to allow the casting to the `enum` type.

You can use the `Cast` method to do the explicit casting for you instead of looping the items yourself:

```
Plugin.MetaDataType[] fields =
  ((ArrayList)parameters["fields"]).Cast<Plugin.MetaDataType>().ToArray();
```

Comment: are you sure? the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/fcyyh2hb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says _All of the objects in the ArrayList object will be cast to the Type specified in the type parameter._

Comment: That answers it perfectly - I was unaware of the inability to cast to enum and the code that did work threw me for a loop in that respect. I'll update the original with the working line.

Comment: @Selman22: For value types the casting is actually unboxing, and you can only unbox a value as the exact same type. This isn't only a limitation for enums, for example you can't use `.ToArray(typeof(long))` on an `ArrayList` containing `int` values although there is even an implicit conversion.

Comment: Then why the second code works? it casts the boxed int to enum type.